# Find unique index for repeating characters in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am looping through an array of strings and their characters to compare their indexes with another array of characters. The code works until the strings have duplicate characters - it then only returns the index of the first (duplicate) character. eg: ["IAMDEFANDJKL"] for "A" and "D" the loop returns only the first index for each occurrence.

eg: ["abode"] returns [1,2,4,5] which then after .length is applied returns [4] - so ["IAMDEFANDJKL"] should return [4,5,6,10,11,12] which then returns [6] (currently returns [7] because "D" occurs twice)

How could I edit the code to return a unique index for all the characters?

```
function solve() {  
  var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
                  'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 
                  'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
  var testArray = ["IAMDEFANDJKL","thedefgh","xyzDEFghijabc"];
  var countArray = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    var string = testArray[i];
    var newArray = [];

    for(var char = 0; char < string.length; char++) {
      var character = string.charAt(char);
      var characterIndex = string.indexOf(character);

      for(var alpha = 0; alpha < alphabet.length; alpha++) {
        var alphaString = alphabet[alpha];
        var alphaIndex = alphabet.indexOf(alphaString);
        var characterUpper = character.toUpperCase();
        var alphaStringUpper = alphaString.toUpperCase();

        if(characterIndex === alphaIndex && characterUpper === 
           alphaStringUpper) {
          newArray.push(alphaIndex);
        }
       var arrayLength = newArray.length;
      }
    }
   countArray.push(arrayLength);
  }

 return countArray;

};

solve();
```

Comment: please add the (wanted) result as well.

Comment: Edited and added

Comment: what string do you compare to which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object and store the last found indices plus one for the next search.

```js
function solve() {
    var alphabet = [...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'];
    var testArray = ["IAMDEFANDJKL", "thedefgh", "xyzDEFghijabc"];
    var countArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        var string = testArray[i];
        var newArray = [],
            lastIndex = {};

        for (var char = 0; char < string.length; char++) {
            var character = string[char];
            lastIndex[character] = lastIndex[character] || 0;
            var characterIndex = string.indexOf(character, lastIndex[character]);

            if (characterIndex !== -1) lastIndex[character] = characterIndex + 1;

            for (var alpha = 0; alpha < alphabet.length; alpha++) {
                var alphaString = alphabet[alpha];
                var alphaIndex = alphabet.indexOf(alphaString);
                var characterUpper = character.toUpperCase();
                var alphaStringUpper = alphaString.toUpperCase();

                if (characterIndex === alphaIndex && characterUpper === alphaStringUpper) {
                    newArray.push(alphaIndex);
                }
              var arrayLength = newArray.length;
            }
        }
        countArray.push(arrayLength);
    }
    return countArray;
}

console.log(solve());
```

A shorter approach by using a check for the same index of the strings.

```js
function solve() {
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        testArray = ["IAMDEFANDJKL", "thedefgh", "xyzDEFghijabc"],
        i, j, count, string,
        result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        count = 0;
        string = testArray[i].toLowerCase();
        for (j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
            if (string[j] === alphabet[j]) count++;
        }
        result.push(count);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(solve());
```

Comment: This is the problem statement: Consider the word "abode". We can see that the letter a is in position 1 and b is in position 2. In the alphabet, a and b are also in positions 1 and 2. Notice also that d and e in abode occupy the positions they would occupy in the alphabet, which are positions 4 and 5.

Given an array of words, return an array of the number of letters that occupy their positions in the alphabet for each word. For example,

solve(["abode","ABc","xyzD"]) = [4, 3, 1]

Comment: please check the second approach.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to understand what is your desired output but I will try.

```
const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
    'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
    'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
const testArray = ["IAMDEFANDJKL","thedefgh","xyzDEFghijabc"];

const result = testArray.map(str => {
    return Array.from(str.toLowerCase()).map((char) => {
        return alphabet.findIndex(alphabetChar => alphabetChar === char)
    })
});
```

Output will be:

```
[ [ 8, 0, 12, 3, 4, 5, 0, 13, 3, 9, 10, 11 ],
  [ 19, 7, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
  [ 23, 24, 25, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2 ] ]
```

Which means it replaces each character of a string with index of this character inside of other array